# Chef Server 12 reconfigure fails with RabbitMQ

Tags: hosts, rabbitmq, chef

After installing Chef Server 12 on CentOS 6.5 everything went well but now I've removed the premium addons that I've installed manually (using RPMs) there is an issue with RabbitMQ:
*It might be related since there is a running RabbitMQ that I think should not be there or is some kind of a renegade...

I'm running:

```
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

Im getting:

```
STDOUT: Waiting for 'rabbit@chef-****' ...
pid is 31466 ...
STDERR: Error: process_not_running
```

I have  also tried to change the RabbitMQ configurations:

```
[***@chef-**** ~]$ sudo cat  /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb
rabbitmq['consumer_id'] = 'curry'
rabbitmq['nodename'] = 'rabbit@chef-****'
rabbitmq['node_ip_address'] = '192.168.***.*****'
rabbitmq['node_port'] = 5678
```

But still, the Rabbit thinks that there is another RabbitMQ there:
sudo chef-server-ctl tail:

```
2015-01-29_03:04:12.18409 node with name "rabbit" already running on "chef-*****"
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18158 diagnostics:
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18191 - nodes and their ports on chef-xxxxx: [{bookshelf,33831},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18196                                             {oc_bifrost,48981},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18196                                             {oc_reporting,44535},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18197                                             {mover,53862},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18197                                             {erchef,41226},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18197                                             {rabbit,25672},
2015-01-29_02:44:28.18198                                             {rabbitmqprelaunch11088,32900}]
```

This might be a clue here, I don't understand why there is another RabbitMQ:

```
[***@chef-**** ~]$ ps -ef | grep rab
root      2147  2124  0 Jan26 ?        00:02:51 runsv rabbitmq
root      2148  2147  0 Jan26 ?        00:01:41 svlogd -tt /var/log/chef-server/rabbitmq
opscode   5815 26954 39 Jan28 ?        06:10:16 /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A30 -P 1048576 -- -root /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq -- -pa /opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../ebin -noshell -noinput -s rabbit boot -sname rabbit@localhost -boot start_sasl -kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] -rabbit tcp_listeners [{"127.0.0.1",5672}] -sasl errlog_type error -sasl sasl_error_logger false -rabbit error_logger {file,"/var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@localhost.log"} -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,"/var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log"} -rabbit enabled_plugins_file "/var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/etc/enabled_plugins" -rabbit plugins_dir "/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../plugins" -rabbit plugins_expand_dir "/var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost-plugins-expand" -os_mon start_cpu_sup false -os_mon start_disksup false -os_mon start_memsup false -mnesia dir "/var/opt/opscode/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@localhost" -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 25672 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 25672
496      13028  2147  0 04:45 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/rabbitmq-server
496      13037 13028 99 04:45 ?        00:00:02 /opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/erlang/erts-5.9.3.1/bin/beam.smp -- -root /opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq -- -pa /opt/chef-server/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../ebin -noshell -noinput -hidden -s rabbit_prelaunch -sname rabbitmqprelaunch13028 -extra /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins /opt/chef-server/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../plugins /var/opt/chef-server/rabbitmq/db/rabbit@chef-*****-plugins-expand rabbit@chef-****
mlev     13073 10972  0 04:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep rab
root     25880 25879  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /opt/opscode/bin/wait-for-rabbit
root     26954 26945  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 runsv rabbitmq
opscode  29822 26954  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/opscode/rabbitmq
[****@chef-*** ~]$
```

Apache quid is not present

```
[****@chef-**** ~]$ sudo rpm -qa | grep qpid
[mlev@chef-**** ~]$  chkconfig --del qpidd
error reading information on service qpidd: No such file or directory
```

After killing everyone's father (and feeling gulty) the RabbitMQ went up but still same problem..

Also:

```
 [***@chef-***** ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    192.168.***.**  chef-**.****.**.***     chef-****
```

Can't understand why Chef can't find it's own RabbitMQ:
    [****@chef-****** ~]$ sudo chef-server-ctl status
    run: rabbitmq: (pid 32391) 1s; run: log: (pid 2148) 208943s

*hostname is the same as in the /etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb*

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE! :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Seeing this issue as well...

Comment: Hi Phillip, I have cleaned everything and re-installed it all but still could not pass this. I could not add the analyze feature yet.

Comment: @Philip Did you managed through ?

Comment: I did but I do not recall the resolution as this was some time ago. Were you able to figure it out @ketzi? Or still battling with it?

Comment: gave up on it ;)